# Store in memory or stalk sqlite in Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory

I have a question regarding my Android app.

Assume 2 tables A and B. A contains some fields and a link to B with an ID. B contains an ID as primary key and a description.

When I display the contents of whole A, I don't want to see the ID of B, but the description.

Table B can contain until 100 descriptions.

What is the best way to do this? Shall I query B for every record of A for getting the description? Or should I read table B into memory and get the description from memory?

I want a good performance, but don't want to use all the available memory on the device.

Later on, A can contain such links to a table C, D, ...

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Use join queries.

[Join samples](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I could smash my head on my keyboard because it didn't come to my mind. It's friday, maybe that's the cause. :-)

Answer (score 0):

100 descriptions sounds like a small amount of data, and using an sqlite database might be like shooting birds with a canon if that is all that you have.

I would use two maps (e.g. `HashMap`), one contains the data of A, and one contains data of B. The id is the key in the maps.

You can switch to a database later if you think that you really need one, just create an interface for getting data.

Comment: The DB is needed because it synchronises with an external MySQL DB when connection is available.

Comment: i don't agree with you. it's always better to use a database when you need to persist data, well in general also (you might want to transfer data between activities, modify only specific rows that contain specific data, have observers on the tables). its true that is more work to setup the database and there are more things you need to be carefull like multiple access etc but if you have a good setup you can expand the functionality of the app without many changes to the core. after all the major part of the dev process is tweaking and expanding functionality.

Comment: And I disagree. You can't say that it _always_ is better than something else. Using a database might not be needed if you have a small amount of dynamic data. The answer on what to use always depends on why you have the data, and what you are going to do with the data. E.g using `SharedPreferences` might be better for configuration data, and using the external storage might be better for other types of data.